# Pass data between two screens or reach app from within python class with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a screen that creates some widgets depending on how many entries there are in a database. Essentially, for each entry in the database there is a little grid added to the screen containing some of the information. Within my `Main(MDApp)` class, I load in the data and add a `TourGrid` widget (written python class inheriting from `GridLayout`) to the screen containing some of the information from the data. What I want is to be able to click on these grids and then navigate to a new page that then allows you to do other things, but working within the framework of this specific entry in the database. The `TourGrid` is clickable, because it also inherits from `ButtonBehavior`, and I can save the id of the database entry in the class which can then be called upon in the `on_press` method. However, I don't know how to switch to another screen from within this grid, and also to pass the data along with it. I can't reach `app` or call `root` from within this structure, and though I can call `self.parent.parent.parent.parent.manager` to get to the screen manager that doesn't seem like the right solution. Ideally I could call it from within the `Main` class so that I don't have to redo the firebase credentials and initialization many times over. How can I achieve this?

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from tour_grid import TourGrid
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from datetime import datetime, date
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db, credentials
import requests
import json


class MyToursScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Main(MDApp):
    acc_id = 0

    def build(self):
        # self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        # self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        Window.size = (360, 600)
        print(Window.size)
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")

    def on_start(self):
        # Get database data
        self.tour_data = {'-abcde': {'acc_id': 0, 'date_tour_created': '28-02-2024', 'ending_date': '', 'name': 'Tour', 'privacy': 'My friends', 'starting_date': '28-02-2024'}
        
        self.populate_my_tours()
        

    def populate_my_tours(self):
            # Populate tour grid on home screen
            tours_grid = self.root.ids["my_tours"].ids["tours_grid"]
            for tour_id, tour in self.tour_data.items():
                tours_grid.add_widget(TourGrid(tour_name=tour["name"], starting_date=tour["starting_date"], tour_id=tour_id))

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:include kv/my_tours.kv

BoxLayout:
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        
        MyToursScreen:
            id: my_tours
            name: "my_tours"
```

tour_grid.py

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.graphics import Color, RoundedRectangle
from kivy.metrics import dp
import kivy.utils

class TourGrid(ButtonBehavior, GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TourGrid, self).__init__() 

        self.tour_id = kwargs["tour_id"]
        self.cols = 1
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(rgb=kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex("#dddddd"))
            self.rect = RoundedRectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos, radius=[(10, 10), (10, 10), (10, 10), (10, 10)])

        self.bind(pos=self.update_pos_size, size=self.update_pos_size)

        # Top layout containing name of tour
        top = AnchorLayout(anchor_x="left", anchor_y="top")
        tour_name_label = Label(text=str(kwargs["tour_name"]), size_hint=[None, None], padding=[dp(8), dp(6)], color=kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex("#000000"), font_name="Proxima Nova")        
        tour_name_label.texture_update()
        tour_name_label.size = tour_name_label.texture_size
        top.add_widget(tour_name_label)

        # Bottom layout containing starting date
        bottom = AnchorLayout(anchor_x="left", anchor_y="bottom")
        starting_date_label = Label(text=str(kwargs["starting_date"]), size_hint=[None, None], padding=[dp(8), dp(6)], color=kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex("#000000"), font_name="Proxima Nova")
        starting_date_label.texture_update()
        starting_date_label.size = starting_date_label.texture_size
        bottom.add_widget(starting_date_label)

        self.add_widget(top)
        self.add_widget(bottom)            


    def on_press(self):
        print(self.parent.parent.parent.parent.manager)
        print(self.tour_id)


    def update_pos_size(self, *_):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size
```

my_tours.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils

<MyToursScreen@Screen>:
    FloatLayout:
        # Top bar, profile image and name, notification and settings button
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            size_hint: 1, 0.075
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            
            canvas:
                Color: 
                    rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#2e6407")
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    
            Image:
                id: account_image

        # Main grid with tours
        ScrollView:
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.825
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.925, "right": 0.9}

            GridLayout:
                id: tours_grid
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                row_default_height: "80dp"
                row_force_default: True
                spacing: 0, dp(8)
                
                Label:
                    text: "Planned trips"
                    color: utils.get_color_from_hex("#000000")
                    font_size: sp(20)
                    bold: True

        # Bottom bar, My Tours, Add Tour and Friends buttons
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
    
            canvas:
                Color: 
                    rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#2e6407")
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

            Label:
                text: "My tours"
                bold: True

            MDIconButton:
                icon_size: dp(50)
                icon: "plus"

            Button:
                text: "Friends"
                background_normal: ""
                background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex("#2e6407")
```

I tried to filter out the unnecessary bits, hope there's no problems!